# YAML Read casts exception

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have an error while reading a file

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String can not be cast to java.util.ArrayList.

Why does it not occur? I'm using YamlSnake lib

`Person.java`:

```
public class Person
{

    int id;
    String fname;
    String lname;
    int age;

    public Person(int id, String fname, String lname, int age)
    {

        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

`yaml.java`:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Person> Read() {

    ArrayList<Person> pp = new ArrayList<Person>();
    try 
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("d:\\Person.yml");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String str=br.readLine();
        Yaml yml = new Yaml();
        pp=(ArrayList<Person>) yml.load(str);
        fr.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return pp;
}
```

`Person.yaml`:

```
-id:2 fname:uu lname:uu age:45
```

Comment: It is hard to tell if your YAML has errors, or if this is a result of inexperience in formatting a post here on [so]. Please look at other posts (you can edit + cancel them) to see how to get a better formatted posting. I also recommend that you have someone more proficient in English review your text. I better understandable post has a much better chance for a quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your YAML syntax. In a block mapping, only one key is allowed per line. Also, there must be a space after both `-` and `:` for them to be recognized as YAML special characters. Try:

```
- id: 2
  fname: uu
  lname: uu
  age: 45
```

If you want to keep it in one line, you can use a flow map instead:

```
- {id: 2, fname: uu, lname: uu, age: 45 }
```

Now the second problem is type erasure. You cannot tell SnakeYaml to load the YAML sequence into an `ArrayList<Person>` because at runtime, even if you tell SnakeYaml you want to have an `ArrayList`, it is impossible to determine the generic parameter `Person`. However, SnakeYaml does provide a possibility to overcome that restriction - alas, it requires you to change your YAML.

Let this be your YAML:

```
persons:
- id: 2
  fname: uu
  lname: uu
  age:45
```

Notice that I placed a YAML mapping as root element, which only contains a key `persons` whose value is the original YAML.

Now, in Java, declare a class that matches this root element:

```
class Root {
    List<Person> persons;
}
```

As before, type erasure prevents SnakeYaml to automatically determine the generic parameter of the type of `persons` at runtime. But now, we can use a `TypeDescription` to carry that information. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public List<Person> Read() {
    Constructor c = new Constructor(Root.class);
    TypeDescription td = new TypeDescription(Root.class);
    td.putListPropertyType("persons", Person.class);
    c.addTypeDescription(td);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(c);

    try  {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("d:\\Person.yml");
        Root r = yaml.loadAs(fr, Root.class);
        fr.close();
        return r.persons;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Collections.<Person>emptyList();
}
```

Beware of bugs in above code, I didn't test it.